# How do I create a shortcut with Shortcut.exe from it's working directory?

Tags: windows, batch, shortcuts

I'm using [Shortcut.exe](http://www.optimumx.com/downloads.html#Shortcut) to make a shortcut for a program in tandem with another batch script. I can easily make a shortcut with a pre-defined path to the program as well as it's shortcut path, but I cannot use an ambiguous path such as `.\`. I want to run my script alongside Shortcut.exe and the target executable *without* defining the executables literal path as it will depend on where the end-user places the script that makes the shortcut. Here is my current working script:

```
Shortcut.exe
shortcut /a:c /f:"%LINKTARGET%" /t:"%TARGETEXECUTABLE%"
```

I want to use something along these lines:

```
Shortcut.exe
shortcut /a:c /f:"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%LINKNAME%.lnk" /t:".\%TARGETEXECUTABLE%"
```

How do I define an executable within the same location as my script and Shortcut.exe?

Comment: The location of the currently running batch can be referred to with `%~dp0`

Comment: I've tried that. Either it doesn't work with Shortcut.exe, or I'm not implementing it properly. I have also tried using various placements of `cd` and `cd..`. Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1316092/edit) your question to contain a more real world example. In general `shortcut /a:c /f:"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%LINKNAME%.lnk" /t:"%~dp0%TARGETEXECUTABLE%"` should do. `%~dp0` already contains a trailing slash.